# read and write commands to auxfile

Tags: macros, auxiliary-files

I have a problem with the aux-file. According to some posts here on Tex-Exchange, the aux-file is read at the beginning of the document (is this at `\begin{document}` or `\documentclass`? I wanted to built a test document. For every run it should increase the number that it is printed on the paper.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}

%Don't overwrite \counti
\ifdefined\counti 
TRUE
\else
FALSE
\newcount\counti
\counti=0
\fi

%make counti raise by 1
\the\counti
\advance\counti by1

%write to aux-file
\makeatletter
\write\@auxout{\noexpand\newcount\counti}
\write\@auxout{\counti= \the\counti}
\makeatother

\end{document}
```

The output is

```
TRUE
0
```

This proves, that it reads the newcount from the aux-file. But unfortunately, the value stays 0. Actually it should raise by one by every run.

The aux-file says

```
\newcount \counti 
\counti = 1
```

after every run.

Comment: It's read before `\begin{document}`  -- is this `TeX` count register stuff really necessary. Have a look on `xassoccnt` package and it's `numberofruns` counter

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I want to write and read two numbers. The number of pages and a custom number. I need them at the beginning of the document. This document has been for tests, to see how things work. If this example works, the actual problem would be solved also. I could use a custom aux-file, but this seems a bit too much for just two numbers. Beside of that I'd like to learn more about Latex.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When LaTeX reads the `.aux` file, then it reads it inside a local group. `\newcount` assigns the count register globally, but the assignment `\counti=...` is local like LaTeX's `\setlength` but unlike LaTeX's `\setcounter`. Therefore the problem can be fixed by a global assignment:

```
\write\@auxout{\global\counti= \the\counti\relax}
```

(I have added `\relax`. Then TeX will not parse beyond to find digits.)

Comment: Thanks. The `\relax` makes sense, because of the `\the`, or doesn't it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a more "latexy" way of doing this using Heiko's [refcount](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/refcount) package. The idea is to save the value of the counter to the auxfile, as a label, and then read it back in each time the file is compiled using `\setcounterref`.

The output of the MWE below takes the form:

[image]

where the value of the counter increments each time.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{refcount}\setrefcountdefault{0}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcounter{TestCounter}

\AtEndDocument{% save counter value to aux file at end of document
  \addtocounter{TestCounter}{-1}%
  \refstepcounter{TestCounter}\label{Ref:TestCounter}% 
}
\AfterEndPreamble{% set counter using value saved in aux file
 \setcounterref{TestCounter}{Ref:TestCounter}%
}

\begin{document}

Counter is \arabic{TestCounter}

\addtocounter{TestCounter}{1}

\end{document}
```

I have automated this using `\AtEndDocument` and `\AfterEndPreamble` commands from the [etoolbox](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package. (This is just for proof-of-concept. There are better ways of writing to the auxfile that avoid decrementing and then incrementing the counter.)